# How to select rows with same ID sharing a group of values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a SQL request for an internal search engine (MySQL db). I want to allow users to search for exact expressions, so when they search for `"foo bar"` they get the documents containing `foo` AND `bar` and not just `foo` or `bar`.

The `search_documents_words` table:

```
| word_id | doc_id | word |
---------------------------
| 1        | 1      | foo  |
| 2        | 1      | bar  |
| 3        | 2      | foo  |
```

The `search_documents` table:

```
| doc_id | doc_name |
---------------------
| 1      | mydoc1   |
| 2      | mydoc2   |
```

What I want to get:

```
| doc_id | doc_name |
--------------------
| 1      | mydoc1   |
```

Assuming that I have my keywords in a PHP array.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Well so far I just have a query that use `IN` function - which is working great, but only for "regular search" : `SELECT sdoc_id, sdoc_document, sdoc_type FROM search_documents_words, search_documents  WHERE sdoc_id = swd_doc AND swd_word IN (" . join(',',$_words) . ") GROUP BY sdoc_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your search keyword is in array

```
$search = array('foo','bar');
$keywords = '';
foreach($search as $values) {
   $keywords .= "'.$values.',";
}
$keywords = rtrim($keywords,","); // creating words as 'foo','bar'
```

then execute this query

```
$query = "SELECT B.*
          FROM search_documents_words A
          JOIN search_documents B ON A.doc_id = B.doc_id
          WHERE A.word IN(".$keywords.")";
```

**EDITED**

This case will work if a same doc id is not repeating word ( doc 1 with many foo entries won't work with this query )

```
$query = "SELECT B.*
          FROM search_documents_words A
          JOIN search_documents B ON A.doc_id = B.doc_id
          WHERE A.word IN(".$keywords.")
          GROUP BY A.doc_id HAVING COUNT(A.doc_id) = '".count($search)."' ";
```

Comment: Don't have MySQL installed, but I think you query needs a DISTINCT before the B.*

Comment: If i'm right this query will just look for `foo` or `bar`, and not `foo` AND `bar`. This is pretty similar to what I'm using for regular search.

Comment: query will look like WHERE A.word IN('foo','bar'); it will look for both foo and bar. try first.

Comment: I just tried it, and using the exact same code I end up with results having only `foo` or `bar`. I added a count column just to be sure of that, and there is many results without `bar` or `foo` (but having one of them), which is not what I'm looking for. If you look at the description of `IN` condition in documentations it make sense : `IN` is made of `OR` and not of `AND`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Let me try, question seem to be interesting..

Comment: Yes that's the good one I think! I just tried it a bit, and so far I have good results with that one. `COUNT` will not be a problem because there isn't any duplicate in `search_document_words` : I have an aditional column named `word_count` that store the number of occurrences of the word. I use it in the "real" request to order the results.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The subquery can be build like this:

```
$keywords = array('foo','bar');
foreach($keywords as $key)
{
  $conditions[] = "word='".$key."'"; 
}
$condition = implode(" AND ",$conditions);
```

Then execute this sql query:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM search_documents 
          WHERE doc_id
          IN (SELECT doc_id 
              FROM search_documents_words 
              WHERE ".$condition.")"
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: It looks like the right answer to me! I'll confirm that as soon the server will be back, I hope this is not this query that made him crash (I have around 30k of keywords and ~5k of documents). For the record, here is the query I end up with : `SELECT sdoc_id, sdoc_document  FROM search_documents_words, search_documents  WHERE sdoc_id = swd_doc AND sdoc_id IN (SELECT sdoc_id FROM search_documents_words WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $conditions) . ") GROUP BY sdoc_id`

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT and HAVING clause

```
 SELECT sd.doc_id, 
           sd.doc_name,
 GROUP_CONCAT(sdw.word     Order by sdw.word SEPARATOR ' ') AS sdwWord
  FROM search_documents sd
  JOIN search_documents_words sdw ON sd.doc_id = sdw.doc_id 
  GROUP BY sd.doc_id, sd.doc_name 
  HAVING sdwWord = <search expression>
```

Comment: How do you manage with this query if keywords are not in the same order than they are in the database ? Because if `GROUP_CONCAT` return `bar foo`, `HAVING` will not accept `foo bar`. Unless there is a function which I don't know about that I can use for that.

Comment: @vard, good point, added order by and it works only for foo bar bit not for bar foo , if you want bar foo also to match then this combo needs to be added to the search_documents_words table